# Три строчки нуждаются в объяснении

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Пытаюсь разобраться в этом коде

1- В макете id.seek это SeekBar, а тип указывается к нему как ProgressBar

2- `mProgress instanceof SeekBar` . [Здесь](http://javapd.blogspot.com/2008/05/25-8.html) написано

> Оператор instanceof проверяет, совпадает ли класс левого операнда с названием класса, заданного правым операндом или является его подклассом.

т.е. совпадает ли класс `mProgress'a` с классом `SeekBar` или является ли `mProgress` наследником `SeekBar'a` .

Правильно ли я понял? Если правильно, то ведь это `SeekBar` наследуется от `ProgressBar` , значит `instanceOf` вернет `false`. Но программа работает, а значит я не понял.

И чем же всё таки является `mProgress` ,`ProgressBar'ом` или `SeekBar'ом`(по разметке).

3- Здесь вообще не понял.

```
private ProgressBar mProgress;
...
// 1.тип указывается  ProgressBar, а привязывается к SeekBar???
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seek);
    if (mProgress != null){
        // 2....
        if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar){
            // 3....
            SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
            seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekListener);
        }
        mProgress.setMax(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут логика такая, так как SeekBar наследуется от ProgressBar, то в общем случае у него присутствуют все родительские свойства и методы и, в общем случае, набор своих, уникальных, которых в родителе нет. Именно для этого проверяется на принадлежность к SeekBar, что бы можно было гарантированно использовать его методы.

Не знаю, насколько поможет такая аналогия, но мне кажется, что так будет более понятно.

Допустим у нас есть некий объект, мы наверняка уверены, что он наследует от View, но какое именно View - не знаем.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.someview);
```

Далее, мы основываясь на некой извращенной логике приложения, предполагаем, что оно может быть либо TextView, либо ImageView

```
if(view instanceof TextView){
    doSomething();
} else if (view instanceof ImageView){
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Можно ли использовать сразу `SeekBar`? не проверяя `instancOf'ом` и указывая тип `SeekBar` сразу. Ведь он так и так наследуется от `ProgressBar'a` и по идее уже имеет свойства и методы родителя.

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen дополнил

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen я с SeekBar'ом дел не имел, может там какое-то страшное колдунство, но я не вижу причин почему нельзя сразу использовать SeekBar, без шаманства с его родителем. Естественно если вы уверены, что в лайоуте действительно SeekBar